# Printing the status of files processed when using find

Tags: shell, find, xargs

I am using multi-procs in 'xargs' to process a bunch of zip files. How to display the count of files processed in multi-procs??

```
find -type f -iname \*.zip | xargs -IZ -P 5 sh -c 'unzip "Z"'
```

How can i get the current number of file being processed..? I just would like to know how many files already processed so far..?
Suppose i have 1k zip files i need to know how many zip files processed so far like.. "Processing file: 200" "Processing file: 400" or "Processing file: 405 of 1000"

Thanks..

Comment: btw. why not just `|xargs -P5 unzip` ?

Comment: ooh okay.. thanks for the comment.. usually.. i might need to extract the files  to a specific directory and specific files hence sh -c enables me to perform those tasks.. find -type f -iname \*.zip | xargs -IZ -P 5 sh -c 'B=/some/new/$(basename -s .zip "Z") ; unzip "Z" '*.tiff' -d $B'

Answer (score 1):

Try to:

```
find -type f -iname \*.zip | xargs -IZ -P 5 sh -c 'unzip "Z"; echo "Z" >> done.txt'
```

and `wc -l done.txt` to see how many are done
or `cat done.txt` to see the list of them.

Please note that it'll fail if new line character is present in any file name. If you have some than use `echo one_more` instead of `echo "Z"` to get at least what you asked for.

Comment: i need to track the number of files processed.

Comment: yes, so use `wc -l done.txt` from another terminal or even `watch wc -l done.txt` as you like